# VBA Copy a PivotTable from another file and change the data source

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a macro part that would copy a sheet with a pivot table from another file to another and change the data range to the one already indicated in the target file. However, when I try, I get two errors once "Subscript out of range" or "Invalid Procedure Call Or Argument Error"
wbStart is a file where there is only a button to start a macro and one tab to be move,
My code:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set wbStart = ThisWorkbook
wbStart.Sheets("Tabela_COREP").Copy After:=wbMe.Sheets(1)
wb.Sheets("Tabela_COREP").PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1").ChangePivotCache wb.Sheets("Tabela_COREP"). _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="corep", Version:=6)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the Macro Recorder while doing it manually? Could give you a good idea about how a code could possibly look like.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i tired, but i got error ' Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)' during this code : `With wb.Sheets("Tabela_COREP")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="corep", Version:= _
        6)
End With`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below i show some solution :

```
Set PivTbl = wbMe.Sheets("Tabela_COREP").PivotTables("Tabela przestawna1")
PivTbl.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="corep", _
        Version:=6)
```